# install4j updater: detect if components are installed

Tags: install4j

I have a net installer with several optional downloadable components and I want to be able to update individual components.

If a user has previously installed component1 and component1 is updated, I want to run the updater

If a user has not installed component1 and component1 is updated, I do not want the updater to run

Is this behaviour possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of install4j 5.1.x this is not possible. Installation components cannot have a separate lifecycle with install4j.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use the API to detect if components are installed? I had a look at `Context.getInstallationComponents()` but it does not seem to be suited for this task.